# How to communicate between Android and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android

I need to communicate Android and Javascript.

I want to call Javascript function in Android and send parameter to Javascript 'a','b','c'

Android:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrILoading(WebView view, String url)

if(url.contains("http://localhost:8080/login.html)){
   view.loadUrl("javascript:setDevice('"+a+"','"+b+"','"+c"');");
```

JavaScript:

```
function setDevice(a, b, c){
    jQuery("#a").val(a);
    jQuery("#b").val(b);
    jQuery("#c").val(c);
}
```

Somebody help me plz..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To communicate javascript with Android webview you should use `Webviewclient` and `Webcromeclient` as

```
 view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not enabled by default in [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Adding the following to the WebView initialization code should take care of it:

```
view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I added that codes. but it doesn't... i did ("javascript:alert("a");)" ("javascript:alert("b");)" ("javascript:alert("c");)" it's shown c->b->a.. Maybe Do i need to use AndroidBridge?

Comment: You would also need to set `view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());` if you have not already.